# Parsing a specific field from an object

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to extract `prayerRequest` from `objects`. However, I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this.

```
var allPrayerRequests = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = PFQuery(className: "PrayerRequests")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

If I do, `println(object)`, I get the following output:

```
<PrayerRequests: 0x7feec8eec7f0, objectId: jy2KwGXenC, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7feec8eca220>";
    prayerRequest = qoiejr;
}
<PrayerRequests: 0x7feec8eed9a0, objectId: KxMpxyWV0P, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7feec8eed600>";
    prayerRequest = qwer;
}
<PrayerRequests: 0x7feec8eee5f0, objectId: DRHBwJpq16, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7feec8eee840>";
    prayerRequest = zxcv;
}
<PrayerRequests: 0x7feec8eeecd0, objectId: cOOdOyv4TM, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7feec8eeef10>";
    prayerRequest = oijg;
}
<PrayerRequests: 0x7feec8eef3c0, objectId: bmO3oVKUDG, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7feec8eef680>";
    prayerRequest = asdf;
}
<PrayerRequests: 0x7feec8eef800, objectId: RcR3wbbMYv, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7feec8eefda0>";
    prayerRequest = qwer;
}
```

So, as you can see in the code, there is a field with `prayerRequest`. I want to be able to extract just this field kind of like if I were to do `println(object.objectId)`, which outputs the following to the console:

```
Optional("jy2KwGXenC")
Optional("KxMpxyWV0P")
Optional("DRHBwJpq16")
Optional("cOOdOyv4TM")
Optional("bmO3oVKUDG")
Optional("RcR3wbbMYv")
```

But just with `prayerRequest` field. Anybody have a way to accomplish this?

Comment: try this object.objectForKey("prayerRequest")

Comment: YES! IT WORKED. Oh my gosh. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PFObject` contains key-value pairs of JSON-compatible data. To get any value you need to use `objectForKey`.

so you can extract it as -

```
object.objectForKey("prayerRequest")
```